# Print copy of real life object, starting with .mpo file or files

Tags: 3d-models, 3d-design, scanning

I want to make a 3D printed copy of a real object. I have access to a Nintendo 3DS which is capable of making 3D .mpo files. Is there a straight-forward method to convert these into a 3D printable model?

Comment: .mpo are stereoscopic photo files, as far as I could discern.

Comment: That is correct. The Nintendo 3DS has a 2 lens camera to take the stereographs.

Comment: I've come close to what I want with a normal camera and photogrammetry software, but have not perfected my skill in it.

Comment: Do you have access to a DSLR camera?

Comment: Even a smartphone can be used for photogrammetry -- especially the last couple generations of iPhone with their lidar feature.  There are a number of YouTube videos on doing your own 3D scanning, with the result that one made with a smartphone was about 95% as good as one made with a $20k dedicated 3D scanner.